# Risky PV01 Vs CS01 for Credit Derivatives

Tags: credit-risk

Can someone please tell if there is a difference between CS01 and Risky PV01 of CDX or CDX Index Options ? Someone told me that they are technically equal only when Par Spread is equal to Standard Coupon, is that correct.

Comment: Can you please post your desk's definitions of "CS01" and "Risky PV01", since neither measure is standardized? CS01 is usually, but not always, the P&L impact from 1 basis point change in the quoted spread. For indices quoted on spread, like CDX IG, you just perturn this spread. For indicex quoted on prices, like CDX HY, you calculate market standard quote spread and perturb that spread. But no one should be using old obsolete "par spread" to calculate CS01 anymore - use "MSQ01" instead, or looking at "par spread" for any reason.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, could it be that CS01 refers to 1 basis point change of Quoted Spread (i.e. flat hazard rate curve) while risky PV01 refers to 1 basis point change of Par Spread (that's computed using piecewise constant hazard curve) taking into account the term structure.

Comment: For example, these random web pages https://fincyclopedia.net/derivatives/r/risky-pv01 and https://fincyclopedia.net/derivatives/c/cs01 seem to define them as the same thing. Yes, it could be that your desk/firm/pricing library defines one of the scenarios as 1bp parallel shift of par spreads.  I suggest you chase down the exact definitions used by your team.  Most people seem to perfer to bump MSQ, but some bump par spreads. Some people bump 1bp in parallel, others prefer to bump spreads 1%. I don't believe there is any standardized definition now.

Comment: @DimitriVulis Could you provide a short definition of "MSQ01"? I'd add this as a new question if meaningful :) Thanks a lot in any case.

Comment: @kermitfrog MSQ01 is the P&L impact of perturbing the market standard quote by 1 basis point. Just emphasizing that you should bump the spread observed in the market, which is not a "par" spread anymore. As a general principle, sensitivities to market observables (e.g. to MSQ spread for CDS, or to swap rate for interest rates) are preferable to sensitivities to something calculated inside model (e.g. to CDS par spread or to hazard rate, or to forward rate for IR). CDS par spreads have not been quoted/observable for years.